# Send request to web service when app gets killed? (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, background, terminate

It's very important for my app to be notified every time the user kills my app (not moving it to the background, but actually quitting it altogether by double-tapping the Home button and swiping my app screenshot up). I know `applicationWillTerminate()` barely ever gets called, so I was wondering what the safest way is to be notified when a user will kill the app. It seems very unlikely that Apple hasn't provided ANY form of solution for this, as a lot of iOS users make it a custom to kill apps when they're done using it, so it would be really really REALLY weird if it would be impossible to catch this event. The only thing I need to do is fire off a `URLRequest` to send some updating instructions to my web service.

Comment: You could try intercepting the `SIG_KILL` or `SIG_TERM` signals, likely one of these two gets send to the app when it gets killed. However not sure if your app is in a position to do much stuff at that time in it's lifecycle (near its end)

Comment: @Cristik Worth a try, I guess. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get more consistency when I add an observer to handle UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification. It gets called when the user double-taps the Home button and swipe the app to kill it.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool 
{
  NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:#selector(AppDelegate.onAppWillTerminate(_:)), name:UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification, object:nil)
  return true
}


func onAppWillTerminate(notification:NSNotification)
{
  print("onAppWillTerminate")
}
```

Comment: Wow, it works! I don't get it. If `NSNotification` has a notification for app termination, then how come `applicationWillTerminate()` barely ever gets called (mainly never)? Why doesn't Apple just implement a delegate method in `AppDelegate` instead of using this notification? Anyway, thanks so much! When I read your answer, I wasn't very confident it was gonna work, since everyone's been telling me for ages it's IMPOSSIBLE to catch the 'app closing' event. Your answer proves so many people wrong. Pleasantly surprised there's a workaround this. Thanks again!

Comment: Still works somehow on iOS 15, but not from background. Try to use appWillResignActive or sceneWillResignActive