# Performing Activity, When the App is Terminated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

i am new in iOS Development so pardon me for asking this question in advance.

I am trying to post some data through API (after a specific time, lets say 30 minutes), I am able to achieve this when the app is in foreground or in background but is it possible to achieve even when the App is terminated ? I can perform this activity while the App is in background through this piece of code

```
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
}];
```

But once the app gets terminated everything stops. I have found out that the thread of an iOS App gets killed after 3 minutes of its termination.

### Presenting UIView after an interval

If the above is possible then is it possible to animate a particular UIView to appear on the screen after a specific time even if the app is terminated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40850846/send-request-to-web-service-when-app-gets-killed-swift-3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your app is terminated it can't execute any code;  You can execute some code *as the app terminates* in `applicationWillTerminate`, if it is called. In many cases it won't be.

On iOS, you cannot execute code at a specific time or after a specific interval if your app is suspended.

You can schedule a local notification to prompt your user to return to your app, but if they don't tap the notification or launch your app from its icon in response then you cannot execute any code.

Comment: And note that `applicationWillTerminate` is not called in many cases. Don't rely on it.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the `applicationWillTerminate:` method of the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate?language=objc). Once the system decides to shut down your application, this method is invoked giving you the possibility to do everything your app needs to do before it can be finished. This could be posting API data to your server as you desire.

Please note that according to the documentation this method is not guaranteed to be called when the user presses the home button but only when the system decides to kill the application:

> For apps that support background execution, this method is generally not called when the user quits the app because the app simply moves to the background in that case.

---

If you don't know about the concept of `Delegates` in Cocoa Programming think of them as a special connection between one instance object (*controller* in the MVC design pattern) of your application (it has to be the app's delegate) and your app itself. The app will tell your *controller* if something interesting did/will happen like application startup or shutdown. Note: This is also available for macOS programming.

Comment: It means i can not perform any activity while my app is terminated?

Comment: It means the following: system decides to kill your app, system informs you that your app will be killed, you now (in the `applicationWillTerminate:`) have the possibility to do everything you want (so indeed you **can** perform an activity here) now and after you are done, the system finally kills your app.